# Specify Optional Arguments when calling functions in Emacs

Tags: search, emacs, elisp

the signature of the query-replace function in emacs looks like this :

(query-replace FROM-STRING TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END)
My question is how can I specify the DELIMITED argument.

The docs indicate: " Third arg DELIMITED (prefix arg if interactive), if non-nil, means replace
only matches surrounded by word boundaries."

So I'm assuming it would be just like a numeric argument specified before a command (i.e. calling undo 8 times with M-8 C-x u) but haven't figured it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(query-replace "foo" "bar" "your demeter")` or `C-u M-%`

Comment: So what if I want to do it in interactive mode? As in: type M-% foo<RET> bar<RET>. When can I specify the delimiter ?

Comment: Ok I got it so any numeric would treat the DELIMITED as non-nil. That works. Now if only I could get M-% to wrap around I would be a happy camper.

Comment: Maybe you just aren't aware of `M-<` (and `M->`).  If you want to do the whole buffer just do `M-<` then do your `C-u M-%`.  Have you done `C-h t`?  It covers basics that will really make your day every day.

Comment: What you are saying is: "You know you can navigate to the beginning of the buffer with M-< and run C-u M-%". Yes I aware I can navigate to the beginning with one simple command but I was hoping of a way that doesn't scroll away from my current view. And yes I did go through the tutorial.

Comment: Then maybe you can do what you want with the mark ring.  See `The Mark and the Region` in the Emacs info pages.

Answer (score 1):

Ross mentioned using <kbd>M-<</kbd> to get to the buffer beginning, then using <kbd>M-%</kbd>. Know too that you can always use <kbd>C-x h</kbd> to mark the whole buffer as the region. (But you do not need to do that here -- just use <kbd>M-<</kbd>.)